# Streamlining OAuth Authentication for Multiple Users in Salesforce Org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli

I am encountering an issue with OAuth authentication for multiple users accessing a third-party app within our Salesforce org. Currently, we have a shared service account or admin account that was initially used to authenticate with the third-party app using OAuth. After the initial authentication, subsequent users within the same Salesforce org are prompted to authenticate individually when accessing the third-party app, which is causing inconvenience and inefficiency.

Problem Statement:

1.After authenticating with a shared service account or admin account, each user within the Salesforce org is required to authenticate individually when accessing the third-party app via OAuth.

2.This results in a repetitive authentication process for each user, leading to a suboptimal user experience and increased administrative overhead.

3.We are seeking a solution to streamline the OAuth authentication process for multiple users within the Salesforce org, avoiding the need for repeated individual authentication after the initial authentication with the shared service account or admin account.

We are seeking guidance, best practices, and potential solutions to implement the Custom Authentication Flow described above within our Salesforce org. Any insights, recommendations, or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.